# Difference between Naishtika Brahmacharya and Sanyasa

Tags: rituals, agni, sanyasi, sannyasa, brahmacharya

What is the difference between Naishtika Brahmacharya and Sanyasa. Specifically in the context of 'Agni'. Since Sanyasa involves 'agni-tyaga'. Does Naishtika Brahmacharya also involve 'Agni-tyaga'?

Comment: Sanyasins cut off sacred thread and shave off their shikhaa. They also abandon fire worship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *Naishtika Brahmachari* is perpetual student. He lives till his death the life that is meant for a student.

> Does Naishtika Brahmacharya also involve 'Agni-tyaga'?

**No**, because after all it is a stage of studentship (Brahmacharya). So, he has to continue performing his duties as a student.

> living at the teacher’s house, the life of a sage, and that There are
>   four orders of life:* the householder’s life, of a forest hermit.  If
>   a man remains steadfast in any of these, he attains bliss.  common
>   prerequisite for all is to live at the teacher’s house following one’s
>   initiation, 4 and all are required not to abandon vedic learning.
>   After he has learnt the rites, he may undertake the order that he
>   prefers
>
> **Following the rules of a novice student,* a student should serve
>   his teacher until death, leaving his body in his teacher’s house.**
>
> **Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 2.22.4**

So, he has to behave like a student (Brahmachari) all throughout his life and thus he can not abandon fire.

More references now from Manu Smriti:

> 2.247. (A perpetual student) must, if his teacher dies, serve his son (provided he be) endowed with good qualities, or his widow, or his
>   Sapinda, in the same manner as the teacher.
>
> 2.248. **Should none of these be alive, he must serve the sacred fire,** standing (by day) and sitting (during the night), and thus
>   finish his life.

Daksha Smriti says:

> Two classes of Brahmacharin have been mentioned by the wise in the
>   Smriti. The first is Upakurvanaka (a Brahmana, in a state of pupilage,
>   who wishes to pass on to the state of a householder); the second is
>   Naishthika (one who leads a life of perpetual celibacy. (8)

Thus, the similarity that they have with Sannyasis is that they should follow a perpetual celibacy till death.

But, absolute renunciation, like is done in Sannyasa, is not for them as said in the following two Harita Smriti verses:

> A Brahmna, whose tongue, generative organ, belly and hands, have all
>   been controlled, should, resorting to Sannyasa (renunciation), lead a
>   celibate life near the same preceptor, as long as he lives ; in his
>   absence near his (preceptor's) son ; [in the latter' s absence,] near
>   his disciple or in his family. **Neither marriage nor [absolute]
>   renunciation is laid down for the Naishthika*** (13,14)

Similarly Usana Smriti says:

> If a twice-born person wishes to lead the life of a perpetual
>   religious student at the house of his preceptor, he should serve him
>   diligently and assiduously till the destruction of his body. (83)
>
> Or (i.e in the absence of his preceptor), going to a forest he
>   should duly offer oblations to Fire. And being self-restrained he
>   should ever and anon study the Spiritual Science. (84)

Comment: Dhanyavaad! That is very helpful. Unfortunately, I don't have enough 'reputation' points to upvote your comment.

Comment: Oh okay no problem ..) @mlprof_24

Comment: see Brahma Sutras 3.4.40-43.