# Is Rama a Naishtika Brahmachari?

Tags: rama, brahmacharya

It is known that Krishna, Narada etc., are married Naishtika Brahmacharis.

Is rama a Naishtika Brahmachari?

Comment: there is no such thing like 'married naishtika brahmachari' - i thought we already settled this in your previous question.

Comment: @ram Yeah, it is askalitha brahmachari :(

Answer (score 4):

No he wasn't because he had married.

There are [four orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashrama_(stage)) of life in Hinduism viz: Brahmacharya (studentship), Grihasta (householder) Vanaprashtha (retired) and Sannyasa (renunciate).

A Naishthika Brahmachari is one who lives in the first order of life perpetually i.e. till his death. He does not marry.

Quoting the necessary verses from [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31731/4732):

> A Brahmna, whose tongue, generative organ, belly and hands, have all
>   been controlled, should, resorting to Sannyasa (renunciation), lead a
>   celibate life near the same preceptor, as long as he lives ; in his
>   absence near his (preceptor's) son ; [in the latter' s absence,] near
>   his disciple or in his family. **Neither marriage nor [absolute]
>   renunciation is laid down for the Naishthika*** (13,14)
>
> (Harita Smriti verses)