# Who was wife of Kripacharya ? Was he married?

Tags: mahabharata

Who was wife of Kripacharya ? Was he married or Was he unmarried ? Is there any such thing mentioned in Mahabharata or any other scriptures ?

Comment: I haven't read anywhere in Mahābhārata as Kr̥pa being married. If he is married, it is not mentioned in Mahābhārata, nor is his wife or any of his offsprings mentioned. His twin sister Kṛpī on the other hand is clearly married to Droṇa. His father, Śaradvān took brahmacarya, so most likely Kr̥pa followed his footsteps and did the same as well (undertook brahmacarya) and probably never married.

Comment: @Bingming  think it was [quite normal thing](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53556/is-it-true-that-a-brahmin-man-can-remain-unmarried-and-be-celibate-his-whole) for a Brahmin man to remain unmarried. I find many brahmin men being unmarried in Puranas and no one cared.While in case of Bhisma (a Kshatriya) , it was considered as a big thing and he was given the name Bhishma just because of it. Aswathama (a Brahmin) was also unmarried.

Comment: I already know all this river. That message was unneeded. I never said Brāhmaṇa can´t remain umarried, also I have read Mahābhārata already, I know all this what you are saying